# Restaurar DataBase.bak sin afectar triggers Actuales SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Como se sobreescribe una `DataBase.bak` en `SQL Server 2008 R2`?. Mientras tengo los Triggers en la base de datos que esta Trabajando. necesito hacer una restauracion de la misma sin afectar los triggers de la vieja database, es decir que solo queden los registros de la data base.

Dicho en otras palabras son mas de 5000 Triggers en la base de datos actual , mientras que la base a restaurar NO TIENE ni uno solo de los Triggers.

REPITO son 5000 Scripts, ¿no creen que da un poco de fastidio? por eso pregunto aquí. Ya estuve buscando y no conseguí ninguna respuesta. Yo solo quiero saber si se pueden restaurar solo las tablas SIN los Triggers.

Comment: Deberías obtener un backup de los scripts de tu base de datos actual y crear ese backup en un script distinto. Luego, al restaurar tu base de datos desde tu archivo .bak ejecutas tu script de triggers.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que saques un Script de la BD incluyendo los datos y en la opción de seleccionar objetos no selecciones los triggers.

Comment: Un archivo .bak es un repaldo completo de la base de datos y cuando restaures ese respaldo no estás afectando ninguna otra base de datos, básicamente estás poniendo en tu lista de bases de datos otra base de datos extra

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría sería sacar el script de los triggers antes de hacer el restore y despues ejecutarlos para crearlos de nuevo, para obtener los triggers se me ocurren dos opciones:

1.- Puedes obtener los triggers con este script (probado en SQL Server 2012)

```
SELECT
   ServerName   = @@servername,
   DatabaseName = db_name(),
   SchemaName   = isnull( s.name, '' ),
   TableName    = isnull( o.name, 'DDL Trigger' ),
   TriggerName  = t.name, 
   Defininion   = object_definition( t.object_id )

FROM sys.triggers t
   LEFT JOIN sys.all_objects o
      ON t.parent_id = o.object_id
   LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s
      ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
ORDER BY 
   SchemaName,
   TableName,
   TriggerName
```

2.- Click derecho en la bd selecciona Tasks>Generate Scripts>Next>Select tables> En 'Advance' selecciona create triggers=true, estos apareceran al final de tu script (si todo sale como en mis pruebas), 
deshabilitando la informacion que no necesites como primary keys o foreign keys [image: Habilitar triggers]